# How to increase the flashing speed using SAM-BA?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to flash my yocto-generated image into a SAM9X60EK board but it's insanely slow, I think it's because of the write buffer size which is only 8KB (and the image is around 150MB) as shown below,

> $ sam-ba -p serial -b sam9x60-ek -a nandflash -c write:microchip-headless-image-sam9x60ek.ubi:0x800000

Output:

> Opening serial port 'ttyACM0' Connection opened.
>
> Detected memory size is 536870912 bytes.
>
> Page size is 4096 bytes.
>
> Buffer is 8192 bytes (2 pages) at address 0x0030aca0.
>
> NAND header value is 0xc1e04e07.
>
> Supported erase block size: 256KB

or

> Wrote 8192 bytes at address 0x00800000 (0.01%)
>
> Wrote 8192 bytes at address 0x00802000 (0.01%)
>
> …
>
> …
>
> Wrote 8192 bytes at address 0x0015c000 (99.83%)
>
> Wrote 8192 bytes at address 0x0015e000 (100%)

Is there any possibility to make this process any faster?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit] your question and tell us: Do you have numbers for even lower buffer sizes? What does the documentation say?

Comment: Hello @thebusybee, thank you:), I actually have no idea if there are any other buffer sizes, this is actually my question, I've just added more detailed output.

Comment: What are you downloading through? SWD or some home-brewed serial bootloader?

Comment: "insanely slow" is a subjective metric.  What is the _exact_ size of the image? How long does it _actually_ take?  You can extrapolate by stating how long it takes to pass through sat 1%.  How can we advise on making it faster until we know how fast it is already.  What are you using to program it (SAM-BA supports JTAG, UART and USB interfaces).  If you are using a serial interface, that is almost certainly the bottleneck here, not the buffer - what speed are you running that at?  At 115200 150Mb will take 3.79 hours - it is not practical.

Comment: Perhaps you should only use SAM-BA serial for loading the AT91 bootstrap and uboot bootloader; the application image can then be loaded from SD card using uboot I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running this command before burning：

sam-ba -p serial -b sam9x60-ek -a lowlevel